# method for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm working on Symfony2.
I'm trying to display some data from my database in a table but I've this exception

> Method "exemplairesParPaquet" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in GPAOPontaultBundle:Fabrication:infogeneral.html.twig at line 103

Can you help me please?

My infogeneral.html.twig

```
<td class='dynamique'>
    {{unDossiers.Conditionnement.exemplairesParPaquet}}
    {{ form_errors(form.Conditionnement.exemplairesParPaquet) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.Conditionnement.exemplairesParPaquet, {'attr': {'style':'width: 80px;pointer-events: none;'}}) }}
</td>
```

My FabricationController.php

```
public function modifierAction(Request $request, $id) { //Action servant à modifier les infos rentrées en base lors de l'enregistrement du formualaire dossier

    $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $unDossiers = $em->getRepository('GPAOPontaultBundle:Dossier')->find($id);
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new DossierType(), $unDossiers);
    if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($unDossiers);
        $em->flush();
        return new Response ('Modification réussi');
    }

    if($unDossiers==null){
         return new Response ('Modification impossible');
    }


    return $this->render('GPAOPontaultBundle:Fabrication:infogeneral.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(), 
        "unDossiers"=>$unDossiers
        ));
}
```

and my DossierType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
       ->add('TitreFaconne', new TitreFaconneType())
        ->add('numDF',  'text')
        ->add('parution',   'text')
        ->add('totalAFabriquer',    'integer')
        ->add('totalAFabriquerMSF', 'integer')
        ->add('cptCloture', 'integer')
        ->add('dateDebutLivraison', 'date', array(
                                            'widget' => 'single_text',
                                            'input' => 'datetime',
                                            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                                            'attr' => array('class' => 'date'),
                                            ))
        ->add('dateFinLivraison', 'date', array(
                                            'widget' => 'single_text',
                                            'input' => 'datetime',
                                            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                                            'attr' => array('class' => 'date'),
                                            ))
        ->add('dateComplet', 'date', array(
                                            'widget' => 'single_text',
                                            'input' => 'datetime',
                                            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                                            'attr' => array('class' => 'date'),
                                            ))
        ->add('observations',   'textarea')
        ->add('Conditionnement', 'entity', array(
                                        'class'=>'GPAO\PontaultBundle\Entity\Conditionnement',
                                        'property'=>'id'))
        ->add('TypeTaquage', new TypeTaquageType())
        ->add('Societe','entity', array('class'=>'GPAO\PontaultBundle\Entity\Societe',
                                     'property' => 'nom'))
        ->add('sauvegarder',    'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')))
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not added element `exemplairesParPaquet` in form builder. Add `exemplairesParPaquet` in form first like other elements and that use it in `twig`.

**Twig will look like:**

```
<td class='dynamique'>
    {{ form_errors(form.exemplairesParPaquet) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.exemplairesParPaquet, {'attr': {'style':'width: 80px;pointer-events: none;'}}) }}
</td>
```

Comment: I have not added `exemplairesParPaquet` in my form builder because `exemplairesParPaquet` is in my entity `Conditionnement`

Comment: Yes that i seen but you need to add it in form builder

Comment: I tried your method but i have an other exception:                       `Neither the property "exemplairesParPaquet" nor one of the methods "getExemplairesParPaquet()", "exemplairesParPaquet()", "isExemplairesParPaquet()", "hasExemplairesParPaquet()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "GPAO\PontaultBundle\Entity\Dossier".`                                                       So, I tried to write the setters and the getter but it doesn't work